# spring-boot-starter-web and com.expediagroup:graphql-kotlin-spring-server in one spring boot app

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, kotlin, graphql

Is it possible to use `@RestController` from `spring-boot-starter-web` or from `spring-mvc` together with `com.expediagroup:graphql-kotlin-spring-server`? I would like to have a Graphql API and a REST API in one spring boot application. But calling `http://localhost:8080/playground` or `http://localhost:8080/graphql` yields 404 until removeing the `spring-boot-starter-web` dependency.